# Alice's mirror reflection in the bathtub scene – simulation glitch or an unexplored sub-plot?

Tags: plot-explanation, dont-worry-darling

In the film *Don't Worry Darling*, at about 57:10, there's a scene where *Alice* goes underwater in her tub, just after a conversation with *Harry* about having a baby.

In that scene, there are several mirrors present and when *Alice* goes underwater -- the reflection in a single mirror isn't in sync with "reality". **In that one reflection, Alice keeps her head above the water** and just looks at the camera.

Was this scene meant to be presented as a simulation glitch? Or is it part of an unexplored \ edited-out sub-plot?

[image: mentioned scene]

Comment: Please write a proper title instead of some jumbled keywords.

Comment: @BCdotWEB "simulation mirror glitch or an unexplored sub-plot?" are a list of jumbled words?

Comment: It might help to write down what you think of when you say 'simulation glitch'. First thing I think about is The Matrix (the déjà vu, specifically), but you might mean it's a VFX error (but then why would someone "present" it?). And why would it be an unexplored sub-plot? Even if it is indicative of obscure(d) symbolism, there is no reason to assume there is a plot connected to it, right?

Comment: @Joachim No, I mean it just as I wrote it -- a simulation glitch -- due to the fact that the scene I'm talking about (just like 90% of the movie) takes place in a simulation.

Answer (score 6):

*This was written before it was quite clear how the plot worked…*
As all the mirrors in the room [square & round] are very carefully placed to always show us multiple reflections of Alice without needing to either CGI out the camera *or* CGI *in* another image, then it makes that shot the *only* CGI shot in the entire scene.

I'd call that pretty intentional.
[I've only watched that one scene, from the point she starts running the bath, so I don't know how it may relate to the plot].

*Late Edit:*
Now I've actually watched the whole thing, I think it's both a simulation glitch… **and** an unexplored sub-plot. It appears to have no connection with any other 'flashback' or 'dream' sequence in the movie. It is one of many increasing instances of 'mental cutaway' we're shown as we're led closer to the reveal, but it seems unlike any of the others.
I would be tempted to call it 'bloody-minded non-revelation', as right the way through there is obviously something 'wrong' with the idyll, yet the 'clues' we are given almost never point towards the actual reveal [which I will not reveal, in case others might like to watch it].
This particular glitch appears to have absolutely no relevance to anything else in the plot.

Comment: although... that doesn't really answer the question: What's that scene for?

Comment: @Luciano -  I haven't watched, as already mentioned. At the time of writing it hadn't been made clear that the 'glitch' could have been a part of the plot itself.

Comment: @Luciano - now i've actually seen it, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple scenes where Alice is interacting with glass and the physics is out of whack. It's a theme. Maybe they just spliced two scenes together. The reflection is looking directly at the camera. The film has a meticulous visual design. No it's not a glitch in the movie editing or CGI, it's a glitch in reality, which up to this point is a significant theme of the movie. It adds to the unease that things are just not quite right.

Comment: yeah, by "simulation" I meant the simulation that (most of) the film takes place at. My question was - is that a glitch in that simulated world? (not in the editing software used during the film's production, I don't think it's reasonable to assume it)

Comment: There's a few examples of glitches in the simulation, like when Alice is cleaning the glass and is almost pushed through (the looking glass?). Or the flashes of vision where she sees the synchronised dancers, or in the ballet room, where she sees Margaret behind the cracked glass. But this is different. Is Alice in the bath, or is she in the mirror watching her simulation in the bath?  Or has she broken the fourth wall while gazing at the filmmakers who are simulating both Alices? Its an interesting question.